# HttpURLConnection : Server return HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-403

I want to download a file with his url.
I use an AsyncTask with HttpURLConnection but when I get response code, server return error 403.
I use the HttpURLConnection in doInBackground.

**Code :**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {

        ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(sUrl[0]);
        fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(sUrl[0]);

        Log.i("Brieg", "storage : /storage/emulated/0/" + fileName + "." + ext);

        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
        }

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        input = connection.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/" + fileName + "." + ext);

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

            if (isCancelled()) {
                input.close();
                return null;
            }
            total += count;

            if (fileLength > 0)
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Where is the problem ?

Knowing that when I get URL in a browser, the download file starts up.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sUrl[0]` Please show how your url looks like.

Comment: `output = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/" + fileName + "." + ext);`. It is no good using hard coded paths like that. It will fail on many devices. What kind of server is it? Where does it reside (LAN/internet)?

Comment: I know, I just use this for test but application stop before.
Url is like this : http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.epub

Answer (score 10):

The cause should be you are not setting User-Agent:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:221.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"); // add this line to your code
connection.connect();
```

Comment: This solved the 403 error in my case. The resource was not forbidden but without "User-Agent" and "Content-Type" was giving 403.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP 403 Forbidden
>   Where is the problem

Error code says it clearly - you are forbidden from accessing the resource on the server. Maybe you need to authenticate first, maybe you are simply banned. Many possibilities.

Comment: When I get the url in a browser, the download file starts up.

Comment: You may want to investigate what exactly is your browser sending - can be cookie, referer, both or anything else server expects to see and as you are not sending it, you get rejected.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The error isn't as clear as you make it sound. I have a file that I can download in a browser, but not via code. I have permission and even tried both setting the authentication used to access hidden parts of the server and disabling SSL verification. Much like the OP, it is likely an issue exclusive to Android's download attempt and the error is a misnomer for it being found but inaccessible.